# C++ error: "size" declared as function returning a function

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why I am getting an error during compilation that says "error: "size" declared as function returning a function" when size() is returning a type size_t. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
// Text.h
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace w3 {
    class Text {
        string* arrayRecords;
        size_t numRecords;
    public:
        Text();
        Text(const char* fileName);
        size_t size() const;
        ~Text();
    };
}

// Text.cpp

#include "Text.h"

namespace w3 {
    Text::Text() {
        numRecords = 0;
        arrayRecords = nullptr;
    }

    Text::Text(const char* fileName) {
        //
    }

    size_t Text::size() const() {
        return numRecords;
    }

    Text::~Text() {
        if(arrayRecords)
            delete [] arrayRecords;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a stray pair of parentheses on the definition.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with this line:

```
size_t Text::size() const()
```

Remove the `()` after `const`, so you have:

```
size_t Text::size() const
```